# Length of string containing hyphens

Tags: string, bash

I would like to calculate the length of a string containing hyphens like `'-----abra-kadabra---'`. How can I do that?

Trying

```bash
he@rp:~ $ s=-----abra-kadabra---
he@rp:~ $ echo $s
-----abra-kadabra---
he@rp:~ $ l=$(#s)
 >
```

Doesn't help me.

Comment: Or it's just a typo, `$(#s)` is **not** what the linked post suggests.

Comment: Of Course, a typo. Sorry about that. H

Comment: Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and use https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score -2):

```
expr length "-----abra-kadabra---"
```

prints: `20`